# fetching data with useReducer

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I am trying to fetch the array of todos and send it using useReducer and Context.
When I console.log(state). I only get an empty array instead of the list of todos. What am I doing wrong?

```
import { createContext, useState, useReducer, useEffect } from 'react';
import { AppReducer } from './AppReducer';

export const GlobalContext = createContext();

export const GlobalProvider = ({ children }) => {
  const [todos, setTodos] = useState([]);

  const loadData = () => {
    fetch('http://localhost:8000/todos')
      .then((res) => {
        return res.json();
      })
      .then((data) => {
        setTodos(data);
      });
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    loadData();
  }, []);

  const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(AppReducer, todos);

  return (
       <GlobalContext.Provider value={{ todos: state }}>
          {children}
       </GlobalContext.Provider>
  );
};
```

Comment: You don't seem to be invoking an instance of AppReducer anywhere in your component. You're just importing it. You're also not using the dispatch method anywhere here. You're using `useState`. WIth useReducer, you modify the state in a switch block *inside* the reducer. Hence - `[state, dispatch]`

The second argument in the useReducer method is the initial values, which should be an object/array, not a state reference.

**edit** I see that you're trying to use the returned todos, but you're not waiting for them. use Async/await if you want to do that.

Comment: You seem to be mixing up using local component state via the `useState` hook and local component state via the `useReducer` hook. Pick one source of truth and stick to it. Your code will use the initial empty array `todos` state as the initial value for your reducer state, and you then never dispatch an action to update `state` so it will just remain the empty array.